# Using Dapper in MonoTouch

Tags: xamarin.ios, dapper

Since I'm a big fan of Dapper and using it for a couple SQL Azure Projects I would like to use on MonoTouch as well against the built-in Mono.Data.SQLite.

I realize that Dapper's speed comes from the dynamic code generation which unfortunately is a big no-no on iOS where everything has to be compiled ahead-of-time by MonoTouch.

First question: Has anyone made any efforts to provide reflection based implementation of the relevant parts of dapper? (I know it will be a LOT slower) If not how hard would it be to implement it (only glanced over the Dapper source).

Second question: I hope I am not sounding naive here but would it be remotely possible to write a little utility that would materialize the dynamically generated IL for your entity POCOs into an IL assembly source file that could be added to your MonoTouch project and thus gets AOTed during build time? Or is this impossible due to joins and QueryMultiple etc?

Note: I realize there is at least [one attempt](https://gist.github.com/1115206) to port Dapper to MonoTouch but glancing over the source I have no idea how's that supposed to fly since all the dynamic method generation stuff is still in there.

Comment: I have been wanting to do this, neuter Dapper so that it can run on MonoTouch, and then look at how to bring in the speed benefits of generated code afterwards. If you want, we could start up a project on bitbucket or something for it.

Comment: Another option is Catnap, here: https://github.com/timscott/catnap It has been working pretty well for us in combination with SQLite.

Comment: I was a bit turned off by Catnap at first because I've read an article where the author didn't get it work but considering your comment I'd might give it a try.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen I've already [begun](https://github.com/oliverw/dapper-dot-net/tree/master/Dapper) but got stuck soon because the dynamic stuff is not documented at all. Earlier revisions of SqlMapper.cs included at least the occasional comment containing the C# equivalent of the dynamic code but the current version of GitHub is tough too read for anyone but the author. Just take a look at SqlMapper.CreateParamInfoGenerator().

Comment: That method creates an action delegate, that when given an `IDbCommand` and an object, will read all the properties of the object and add parameters for each. Basically it generates code for: `command.Parameters.Add("Name", obj.Name);` and then for each property.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen Yes of course. I've figured out that pretty quickly. I just can't make any sense of the stuff further down in that method where it deals with null checking etc.

Comment: @OliverWeichhold it is likely you do not need many of the fancy tricks there, try porting a trivial param extractor and materializer ... that is the only stuff you would really need... don't mind having this in dapper.contrib if you wish